# MPEG-4 videos from AVAsset are far larger than the original video

Tags: ios, video, uiimagepickercontroller, avasset

When I select an MPEG-4/MP4 video from either `UIImagePickerController` or our custom image picker, the `AVAsset` requested has a file size that is much larger than the original video, even though it is shown on the device and in iCloud Photo Library as the smaller size.

For example, a test MP4 video that I saved to my device is listed as 73.5MB in Photos, but the `AVAsset` shows it as approximately 437MB.

Our custom image picker does no processing on the video; `UIImagePickerController` displays an editing view, after which it takes a few seconds to "compress" the video. Both methods show the 437MB file size in the end.

Should we process videos separately after the image picker completes, or is something else going on here?

Edit: Here's the code we're using to determine the file size:

```
@objc var fileSize: Int64 {
    guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else {
        return 0
    }

    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mov

    let duration: CMTime = CMTimeMultiplyByFloat64(exportSession.asset.duration, 1)

    exportSession.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, duration)

    return exportSession.estimatedOutputFileLength
}
```

And [here's a sample video](http://www.dvdloc8.com/clip.php?movieid=12167&clipid=1) that triggers the issue

Comment: how do you determine the size of the `AVAsset`?

Comment: Do you have an example file?

Comment: @Krystian: I updated the question with sample code and a sample video. I've tried changing the export preset and file type but it results in little to no change in the file size.